# send log on loggly using log4net-loggly

Tags: c#

">    i am using this code in web.config to send log to loggly.not able to send     log to loggly. please help to send log."

```
  <configSections>
 <section name="log4net"type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net configSource="Log4.config">
<root>
  <level value="ALL"  />
  <appender-ref ref="LogglyAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="LogglyAppender" type="log4net.loggly.LogglyAppender,       log4net-loggly">
  <rootUrl value="http://logs-01.loggly.com/" />
  <inputKey value="00edc871-1227-4c34-af25-088b1befc723" />
  <tag value="log4net" />
  <userAgent value="log4net" />
  <!--<logicalThreadContextKeys  value="LogicalThread1,InnerLogicalThreadContext" />
  <globalContextKeys value="GlobalContextPropertySample" />-->
  </appender>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger   [%property{NDC1}] - %message%newline" />
   </layout>
 </appender>
</log4net>


 private static readonly log4net.ILog log =
               log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Dec   laringType);

log.info("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 7.2 change url to https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/

Answer (score 0):

I would have written this as a comment but apparently it won't let me.

As of Loggly's latest version at this point (7.2.1), I had to use the following configuration:

```
<appender name="LogglyAppender" type="log4net.loggly.LogglyAppender, log4net-loggly">
  <rootUrl value="https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/" />
  <logMode value="inputs" />
  <inputKey value="YOUR TOKEN" />
  <tag value="log4net" />
</appender>
```

Comment: You have to use loggly api to send the logs. Implement the there is an interface which contain one method send(). Implement that interface and override the function and make a http request for https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/  url. It will send your logs.